# Django form submit with hundreds of Celery tasks

Tags: python, django, ajax, forms, celery

I have created a system that enables a user to select users and notify them. When they submit their form, the code will execute a celery task to notify each user. I am getting browser timeouts when sending to 100s of users.

Here is a simplified version of my code. Note that my code works as intended, it's just slow when # of users gets into the 100s. Happy to add more if it helps with the answer, but I really want to focus on the generalizable crux of the issue.

Note that there reasons why I need so many editable inputs that I'd rather not get into. Let just assume that they are a constraint for the purpose of this question.

### HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Input 1</th>
            <th>Input 2</th>
            <th>Input 3</th>
            <th>Input 4</th>
            <th>Select</th>
        </tr>
        {% for u in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>u</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="input-1-{{u}}" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="input-2-{{u}}" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="input-3-{{u}}" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="input-4-{{u}}" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="input-4-{{u}}" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select-{{u}}" value="True"></td>
        </tr>
        {% endif %}
    </table>
</form>
```

### Views

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    
    # users is a queryset
    for u in users:
        
        # input-#- is a form input associated with each user
        input_1 = request.POST.get('input-1-%s' % u, '')
        input_2 = request.POST.get('input-2-%s' % u, '')
        input_3 = request.POST.get('input-3-%s' % u, '')
        input_4 = request.POST.get('input-4-%s' % u, '')

        # a message is compiled from these inputs
        message = 'Hello, %s, %s, %s, %s' % (input1, input2, input3, input4)
        
        # select- is the 'name' of a checkbox associated with each user
        if request.POST.get('select-%s' % u, False):
            notify_user.delay(u, message)
```

I execute retrieval of form information outside of celery since I cannot pass request through to a celery task, and the forms often contain hundreds of fields. I find that this works well up to about 200 selections (each with its own celery task), after which browsers begin to time out.

I can think of a couple ways to proceed:

1. **Combine celery tasks into a single task.** I would probably put all of the messages into a dict associated with each user and pass that into a single celery task that I could then use to send all of the messages.
2. **Keep as is but use AJAX to submit the form.** This would enable me to keep the celery tasks small, but want to ensure that this is the way to go before proceeding, as I am less familiar with using AJAX to submit large forms.
3. I am sure there are plenty of other ways

Any suggestions on best practice for submitting so many tasks using a large Django form submission?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you should start with 1. and if that does not work out, ask a specific question we can give a good answer on.

Comment: You can serialise the POST data and put that into your celery store (redis ?) - then your celery runner can pick that up and do what it needs asynchronously to your http request lifecycle